# third out of four child divs, take up remaining width of parent

Tags: css

I need the 3rd out of 4 children of a div to take up the remaining space. Here is some sample code im working with https://jsfiddle.net/68s5q34v/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="remaining">
      remaining
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  background-color:tomato;
  padding:4px 0;
}
.menu{
  background-color:orange;
  width:300px
}
.one,.two,.three{
  background-color:dodgerblue;
}
.remaining{
  background-color:green;
}
.menu,.one,.two,.three,.remaining{
  padding:5px;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

the width of [one][two][remaining][three] are **unknown**.

[one],[two],[three] should only take up as much space as they need for their inner text.

[remaining] should take up what remains, pushing [three] to the end, essentially not showing any orange.

note:
There are similar questions, but! i cant find one that matches my question with the detail that my child elements **does not** have a set width.

Comment: repeating the same question will lead to the same closure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73603191/8620333 .. and you edit doesn't make sense. 2 items of 4 items won't change the method you have to use which is the same (even if you don't have fixed width as well). Take the time to learn and understand Flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for `display: flex` approach;

Apply `display: flex` for `.menu` and `flex: 1;` for `.remaining`

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  background-color:tomato;
  padding:4px 0;
}
.menu{
  background-color:orange;
  width:300px;
  display: flex;
}
.one,.two,.three{
  background-color:dodgerblue;
}
.remaining{
  background-color:green;
  flex: 1;
}
.menu,.one,.two,.three,.remaining{
  padding:5px;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="remaining">
      remaining
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
the width of [one][two][remaining][three] are unknown.
<br/><br/>
[one],[two],[three] should only take up as much space as they need for their inner text.
<br/><br/>
[remaining] should take up what remains, pushing [three] to the end, essentially not showing any orange.
</p>
```

Comment: thank you for actually reading my question, and solving it. much appreciated!

Comment: @Jason it's funny that you complain about the duplicate and end accepting an answer that is exactly the same as in the duplicate ...